npm install express ERROR!! how to solve the problem
ingcabucabi@MacBook-Air-khxng-Ing feelfriends % npm install express
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /path
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/path'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /path/to/another/directory/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal

in my folder's feelfriends have package.json, I want to install express but have and error on my folder

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This totally depends on the project which is available only to you
